# How to check id logged in where condition?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a isAdmin() which return true if exist record. I have 2 where condition. I first I check if role is Admin and second where check if id is user logged id. And my problem is how I check to second where id currently logged id user.
model

Comment: Is your main problem is to check with a method whether the logged in user `role` attribute is `Admin` or not? I think the operation you're trying to do overcomplicates the issue.

Comment: @cengsemihsahin So what diffrent way I can do that ?

Comment: If you want to do this via a **method** did you see my answer? Or you can use syntax like `auth()->user()->role == 'Admin'`.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has an `Auth` facade that can help retrieve user details. So basically add it to the top of your file then call it as such:

```
use Auth;
public $userId = Auth::user()->id;

protected $fillable = [
    'login',
    'password',
    'email',
    'role',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password',
];

public function isAdmin()
{
    return User::where('role', 'Admin')->where('id', $userId)->exists();
}
```

Although it is much better to do this in your controller instead.

Comment: When I create `public $userId = Auth::user()->id;` show me error `expression is not allowed as field default value`

Comment: @perh23 Can I see your code?

Comment: I modifiy my post, add code whole model

Comment: @perh23 You did not add ```use Auth```

Answer (score 0):

To use anywhere like this:

```php
auth()->user()->isAdmin() // returns true or false
```

You can update the `isAdmin()` function in your `User` model like this:

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->role == 'Admin';
}
```

This will give you whether the logged in user has the `Admin` role.